# Add kilometers to a map point

Tags: php, latitude-longitude, points

Good morning.

I would like to know how do I add kilometers to a map point (latitude / longitude).

For example: The city Jaraguá do Sul is in latitude -26.462049, longitude -49.059448. I want to add 100 kilometers up, down, and on the sides. I want to do a square and get the new points.

How do I do that?

I tried it:

```
<?php
$distance = 100;
$earthRadius = 6371;
$lat1 = -26.4853239150483;
$lon1 = -49.075927734375;
$bearing = 0;

$lat2 = asin(sin($lat1) * cos($distance / $earthRadius) + cos($lat1) * sin($distance / $earthRadius) * cos($bearing));
$lon2 = $lon1 + atan2(sin($bearing) * sin($distance / $earthRadius) * cos($lat1), cos($distance / $earthRadius) - sin($lat1) * sin($lat2));

echo 'LAT: ' . $lat2 . '<br >';
echo 'LNG: ' . $lon2;
?>
```

But it's returning wrong cordinates. Thank you!

Thank you very much.

Comment: The 2 answers so far are the general approach.  But if precision isn't critical, AND if the geographical area of interest is limited -- specifically, within a narrow band of latitude -- then you can fudge these functions.  I wouldn't be able to provide details of "how wide a band" and "how much imprecision."
Then again, if the geographical scope is limited, you could just make a look-up table :-)

Comment: If you specify more about your app, final goals, or working tools, you may get news on a specific solution (example, CoreLocation for iPhone)

Comment: I'm creating a PHP application and I have a database table (cities) with every city in my State (Santa Catarina). In this table, I have latitude/longitude fields.

The user enter the city and I need to create a imaginary square of 100km to find enterprises near him.

Sorry about my english and sorry about lack of information.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 7):

as was already pointed out. PHP trigonometric functions take radians as paramters.

degree to radian conversions of the parameters will do the trick. you probably want the result in degrees, so use rad2deg to convert back:

```
<?php
$distance = 100;
$earthRadius = 6371;
$lat1 = deg2rad(-26.4853239150483);
$lon1 = deg2rad(-49.075927734375);
$bearing = deg2rad(0);

$lat2 = asin(sin($lat1) * cos($distance / $earthRadius) + cos($lat1) * sin($distance / $earthRadius) * cos($bearing));
$lon2 = $lon1 + atan2(sin($bearing) * sin($distance / $earthRadius) * cos($lat1), cos($distance / $earthRadius) - sin($lat1) * sin($lat2));

echo 'LAT: ' . rad2deg($lat2) . '<br >';
echo 'LNG: ' . rad2deg($lon2);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A big topic.  Here are some intro links:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~cvm/latlongdist.html

Comment: I was about to post your first link, too :)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

PHP trigonometric functions take radians as Paramters, not degrees, so you need to use deg2rad() as a parameter:

```
sin(deg2rad($lat))
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.deg2rad.php

---

Original answer:

A big Topic indeed.

Depending on your required precision ( and distances covered), you might have to take into account that earth is not a perfect sphere, but a geoid  ( a flattened elipsoid).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius

will get you started on this.

Mapping and projection are two topics you should take a look at, too

another link from wikipedia on the topic of distances

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Comment: Where is this planet 'erath' and how did you get here?

Comment: Just get another 200 reputation and edit typos if you find them ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your new information, I have two alternative approaches.
(1)  Google "PHP GIS".  You will find some interesting resources.  Maybe one will work.
(2)  If your enterprises are identified by lat-longitude, then you will have to use (1) I think.  But is there a "dumber" approach?  For example, if each enterprise is linked to a city, then use simple map coordinates ("K16") to identify cities.  Or something a bit smarter code-wise, but that's the idea.